# Adding controls to dropdown

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

> I need to add a link button control to dropdown list item.is it possible to add child controls to a drop downlist ?if not how can i
>   achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add controls to Dropdown list, why you want to do so ?
Use GridView, DataList and Repeater control instead.

Answer (score 2):

a drop-down list only supports text (so to speak) and NOT child controls.  You are going to have to simulate this with a textbox, image button ( the down arrow ) and a div that toggles hidden/visible when you click the image. I believe that [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) has such a control

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Because Dropdown list rendering as SELECT tag in HTML. You can create custom dropdown like control using DIV. Or use any technologies like Silverlight or Flash

Answer (score 0):

Like Maud'Dib mentioned, [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/why.aspx) is the best route to take if you want a very packaged solution.

If you want to use a free package, use [ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DropDown/DropDown.aspx) drop down control and render the div with an image in front.

If you want a light weight solution, use [jQuery](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)